# Error of sendUserActionEvent() mView == null is coming

Tags: json, httpresponse, android-volley

I am parsing a json response file got through the Volley Request Libraries and populating List by the json array.

```
public  void getAllContacts() {

        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
          String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

            String url = "http://52.25.169.219:3000/users";



                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                            url, null,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    try {
                                        JSONArray cast = response.getJSONArray("users");
                                        for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) 
                                        {
                                            JSONObject actor = cast.getJSONObject(i);
                                            String name = actor.getString("name");
                                            String phoneno =  actor.getString("contact");
                                            name1.add(name);
                                            phno1.add(phoneno);
                                        }




                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                    //                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    VolleyLog.d("Tag", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in fetching contacts", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }
                            });

                    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                    queue.add(jsonObjReq);
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
                    progressDialog.show();
```

}

But getting volley error and toast as error in fetching contacts.

My json file format is

```
{"users":"[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"test_name\",\"contact\":\"23456543\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"age\":234,\"city\":\"delhi\",\"state\":\"india\",\"created_at\":\"2015-07-19T17:58:42.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-07-19T17:58:42.000Z\",\"district\":\"test_district\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"test_name\",\"contact\":\"23456543\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"age\":234,\"city\":\"delhi\",\"state\":\"india\",\"created_at\":\"2015-07-19T17:58:42.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-07-19T17:58:42.000Z\",\"district\":\"test_district\"}]"}
```

Error is

```
08-02 21:20:57.264: E/ViewRootImpl(31835): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Comment: Please help me. I have tried so many things but unable to find the solution.

Comment: I don't know but it may be some volley error. but where is it. i am unable to find. please help.

Comment: Getting same issue